# Set Width of Mvc Telerik Tabstrip According to content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I use telerik tabstrip in my mvc 3 application. I have a table inside a tab which has a large amount width. But tabstrip has fixed width.

I want tabstrip to enlarge with it's content.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using jQuery.

After the page is loaded, find the computed width of your table then set that width (or more) to your tabstrip.

Example :

```
$(function () {
    $("#TabStrip").width($("#YourTableId").width());
});
```

"#TabStrip" is the id you gave your tabstrip, which is set with the "name" method like follow

```
Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("TabStrip")...
```